# JSON encode. Force an item to be always an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a simpleXML object and I must convert it to a JSON to be passed to AJAX. My solution almost always work and the JSON returned is something like this one:

```
{
   "error":false,
"data":{
  "name":"C45",
  "nParameters":"3",
  "seed":"0",
  "nOutput":"1",
  "parameter":[
     {
        "name":"Podado",
        "type":"list",
        "domain":{
           "item":[
              "TRUE",
              "FALSE"
           ]
        },
        "default":"TRUE",
        "name_orig":"pruned"
     },
     {
        "name":"Confianza",
        "type":"real",
        "domain":{
           "lowerB":"0",
           "upperB":"1"
        },
        "default":"0.25",
        "name_orig":"confidence"
     },
     {
        "name":"InstanciasPorHoja",
        "type":"integer",
        "default":"2",
        "name_orig":"instancesPerLeaf"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

As you can see, there is a value called `item`. This item has a variable length and my problem arise when in the XML file, the tag `item` appear only once as a children of tag `domain` because the resulting JSON doesn't store the value `item` as a JSON array and I need that value as a JSON array always. So what I want is to "force" the creation of such value as an array.

For `parameter` I had the same issue, but I could solve it with this code:

```
if ($parsedXML_actual->nParameters <= 1) {
             $xmlArray = (array) $parsedXML_actual;
            if ($parsedXML_actual->nParameters == 1) {
                $a = array($parsedXML_actual->parameter);
            } else {
                $a = array();
            }
            $xmlArray['parameter'] = $a;
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'data' => $xmlArray));
        }
```

I've been trying to apply the same way to `item` but I can't find the way to go down more levels securely (`item` does not always exists, as you can see)

Is there any possible way to do this?

EDIT 1:  This is my source XML:

```
    <algorithm_specification>
       <name>C45</name>
      <nParameters>3</nParameters>
      <seed>0</seed>
      <nOutput>1</nOutput>
      <parameter>
        <name>Podado</name>
        <type>list</type>
        <domain>
          <item>TRUE</item>
          <item>FALSE</item>
        </domain>
        <default>TRUE</default>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
    <name>Confianza</name>
    <type>real</type>
    <domain>
      <lowerB>0</lowerB>
      <upperB>1</upperB>
    </domain>
    <default>0.25</default>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>InstanciasPorHoja</name>
    <type>integer</type>
    <default>2</default>
  </parameter>
</algorithm_specification>
```

As you can see, Value "name_orig" in JSON is added after reading and parse the xml

Comment: what's your input xml?

Comment: You can traverse the object, but first: are you sure that is the place you need to fix `item`? What problems do you get when it's not an array?

Comment: @Gavriel In edit 1 is the source XML

Comment: @Shomz I don't know what problem is, is none of my business. My teammate told me that value must always be an array.

Comment: *"my problem arise when item has only one item or zero item because the value of the item field is not an array"* – Please be clearer on the details here. What else is it? How does it get that way?

Comment: @deceze I edit that line. Maybe now it is clearer than before (it is hard to explain).

Comment: @ÁngelMiguelGarcíaVico, 1st of all it's clear that the input, code, output you represented don't mach (see name_orig: where does it come from?)  Secondly, where the xml input doesn't have "item", the output doesn't have it. Either you'll need to change the xml format to include let's say <items></items> around the items, so this way it would* at least show up in the output (though not as an array) OR you should add something to the code to tell it you always want an array there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ($parsedXML_actual->nParameters <= 1) {
        $xmlArray = (array) $parsedXML_actual;
        if ($parsedXML_actual->nParameters == 1) {
            $a = array($parsedXML_actual->parameter);
        } else {
            $a = array();
        }
        for ($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
            if (!isset($a[$i]['domain'])) {
                $a[$i]['domain'] = array();
            }
            if (!isset($a[$i]['domain']['item'])) {
                $a[$i]['domain']['item'] = array();
            }
            if (!is_array($a[$i]['domain']['item'])) {
                $a[$i]['domain']['item'] = array($a[$i]['domain']['item']);
            }
        }
        $xmlArray['parameter'] = $a;
        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'data' => $xmlArray));
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!